# Why is Dexion Evicus attacking me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I rescued Dexion and he immediately began attacking me.  Serana beat him down and we got out of the cave, but he was outside with us and began attacking again.  Serana beat him down again and I was able to fast travel to the Dawnguard hold.  He was inside and was attacking everyone.

I've tried:

- changing his faction
- setting his hostility to 0
- teleporting him outside the hold

One of the above console commands did something to him because now he's just standing still, but he's "busy", so I cannot interact with him.  I no longer have the auto save from before I rescued him, so I am going to need some console magic to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone seems to find a different solution that works for them and not others.  The one that worked for me was using the console command to disable Dexion and then enable him.  After enabling him, he advanced to the next step and the quest continued on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The way I fixed it was by using the *Bend Will* shout from the Dragonborn DLC. He stops attacking and sheaths his weapon.